# locale-gen on ubuntu 13.04 server doesn't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locale, ubuntu-13.04

As I need my locale which is `fa_IR.UTF-8` on my `Ubuntu 13.04 Server`, I'm trying to install it through `(sudo) locale-gen "fa_IR.UTF-8"` but I don't get any output:

```
user@s1:~# sudo locale-gen "fa_IR.UTF-8"
user@s1:~#
```

AND IT DOESN'T ADD ANY LOCALE to my locales!

When I'm trying to install new locales on my `Ubuntu Desktop` I don't get this error and It works well! as follows:

```
user@s1:~# sudo locale-gen "fa_IR.UTF-8"
Generating locales...
  fa_IR.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
user@s1:~#
```

Please help me what's the problem and what shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I could find the solution by doing some things manually:

1. check which locales are supported :

   ```
   less /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
   ```
2. Add locale to list of generated

   ```
   (sudo) echo fa_IR.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
   ```
3. Regenerate list (it will invoke locale-gen...)

   ```
    (sudo) dpkg-reconfigure locales
   ```

Comment: This question and the answer caused an improvement on Ubuntu! just refer to this question on askubuntu.com https://askubuntu.com/questions/753516/locale-gen-doesnt-work/753522#753522